# How does this text reformatting happen with ack?

Tags: shell, ack

If I do a plain `ack` for a string, I get a line with the filename, and then the line numbers and the matching lines, like so:

```
$> ack function
mymodule.file
8: function myfunction1() {
16:  public function __construct( $protocol = 'ftp') {
36:  public static function getSupportedProtocols() {
```

However, when I `ack` the results for a second string, the lines come out with more information on a single line:

```
$> ack function|ack test
mymodule.file:897:function mytest() {
```

I noticed this also happens when grepping the results of `ack`.

How is the information on various lines being reduced to one line? Is it the shell doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by `ack` itself. `ack` checks if its standard output is connected to a terminal, and if it isn't, it prints output in a different format. I guess this format was chosen because it is more easy to process by applications designed for text processing (like `grep` or `ack` itself).